# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps not showing in VS code Duplicated

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint

This config refers to a React Native project.
For some reason the VS Code is not warning about the dependencies on useEffect, useCallback etc
What am I missing?

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
    'react-hooks',
    'prettier',
    'eslint-plugin-import-helpers',
  ],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'warn',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn',
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'warn',
  },
}
```

Needed dependencies aren't being shown by VSCode

Comment: And the eslint vscode extension has been installed? If so view the debug by going to View --> Output and selecting eslint from the dropdown in the panel that opens. Possibly errors relating to your setup are reported there.